# Is it possible to do \par with zero \parskip for the next paragraph?

Tags: spacing

I'm trying to break the paragraph and I can't use `\newline`. I need to use `\par`. However, I need to skip the vertical space between paragraphs caused by `\parskip`. Here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\setlength\parskip{12pt}
Hello,
\par % Only here I need to skip the 12pt vertical space
world!
\end{document}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: `\par\vspace{-\parskip}`?

Comment: The first reply that pops out of my mind is: why would you need such a thing? If you decide for a nonzero parskip, keep with it. If in some place you feel that the parskip is out of place, then you shouldn't start a new paragraph.

Comment: (why not use a blank line, using `\par` in the document body looks rather unusual) how is the reader supposed to know this is a new paragraph? and if they should not see it as a paragraph why not use `\\ ` to get a linebreak?

Comment: Interestingly, \unskip doesn't work here.

Comment: Why couldn't you use `Hello,\hspace{fill}\strut\\ World.`?  (Yes, I know that `\\ ` isn't generally recommended, but there are some situations ...)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Enclose the portion of the document you need change its `\parskip` with `{` and `}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}

\begin{document}
    
{   
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
Hello,
\par % Only here I need to skip the 12pt vertical space
world!
}

Hello,
\par % Only here I need to skip the 12pt vertical space
world!

\end{document}
```

Comment: the braces only need to be around the first word of the second paragraph (that starts horizontal mode). also `\vskip-\parskip` is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, but you should think twice about this: what would it mean to the readers?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\noparskip}{%
  \par\vskip-\parskip
}

\setlength\parskip{12pt}

\begin{document}

Hello, world!

Hello,

\noparskip

world!

\end{document}
```

[image]